# 80s VHS tracking effect

Tags: sound-effects, logic-pro, pitch-shifting, modulation

I'd like to grab all of the tracks in a particular project and modulate all of them so that it sounds like they are slowing down slightly and going out of tune. This is the effect that you'd hear back in the day with VHS when the tape player was in tracking mode.

How can I go about achieving this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple beautiful plugins for achieving this effect that are fun to even use in tandem for a richer warble:

- https://www.xlnaudio.com/products/effect/rc-20_retro_color
- http://www.psychicmodulation.com/echomelt.html

I endorse both enthusiastically! And if you want some more grit and hiss, add TB ReelBus to your arsenal. It's designed to simulate magnetic tape machines but can do a nice cassette-VHS-y thing quite well! https://www.toneboosters.com/tb_bustools_v3.html

Happy oldizing and agefying!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this effect is to use a pitch shifter plugin on the master chain or in a grouping of tracks you want to target. In Logic Pro X, there is a plugin called Pitch Shifter. I set the mode to manual, turn the wet nearly all the way up and then just automate the fine pitch knob. If you couple this with some low pass filter EQ'ing, you have the poor-man's VHS warp effect.